# Can I use the .perl_env file to set env variables?

Tags: perl, variables

I am new at configuring perl and I'm trying to find the best way to set some common variables. I know there are lots of ways of doing this but I want to find the "best" ;). I came a crossed the .perl_env file in my root dir but can't find much documentation on it. Is this a place I can keep variables like BINDIR and VARDIR  (locations that I use in my perl scripts) or is there a better way. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everyone else, I've never heard of a `.perl_env` file. Also I'm assuming you mean that you want to set Perl global variables, since if you mean to set system global variables (environment variables) you should be doing that in a Bash script.

Anyway, if you really wanted to do this I would make a file named `MyGlobalVariables.pm` and place it in your PERL5LIB directory.

```
package MyGlobalVariables;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw/$SomeVar/;

our $SomeVar = 'Some Value';
```

Remember that each variable must be added to the `@EXPORT` array.

Then in your scripts you can write `use MyGlobalVariables;` and voila, there they are. This mechanism is a lot like a custom style file in LaTeX; of course that is a macro language.

All that said, I really don't think this is a good idea. Why? Two reasons:

1. You cannot see the initialization of these variables, to remember you have to go look in the other file.
2. These variables must be true globals rather than lexicals. One always should use lexicals (`my` rather than `our`) unless there is a real reason to do so.

Comment: Why don't you think this is a good idea? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Hum, I've never heard of `.perl_env`, and it's not in the documentation:

```
$ perldoc perlrun | grep .perl_env || echo "not found"
not found
```

But let's give it a try anyway.

```
$ echo '$ENV{FOO}="BAR";' >~/.perl_env

$ FOO=BAZ perl -E'say $ENV{FOO}'
BAZ
```

Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: Well I guess that file was setup on my system somehow :P. Still how should I handle variables like BINDIR?

Comment: @Bill, What's BINDIR? It's not a valid Perl variable name.

Comment: Ya, it a variable that I want to treat as a "global variable". I use it in a lot of my scripts and i want it available to those script and in set in one location

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to answer this new question.

Comment: not only is `.perl_env` not in the documentation, when one googles for it, the ONLY 2 RESULTS point back here! I don't know that I've ever googled for something with essentially no hits!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with a configuration file to share variables between scripts, see the following example :

**INPUT file**:

```
$ cat /tmp/config 
[name1]
    val1=foobar
    val2=qux

[name2]
    val1=10
    val2=100
```

**Perl code** :

```
$ perl -we '
    use Data::Dumper;
    use Config::IniFiles;
    my $ini = new Config::IniFiles(
        -file => "/tmp/config", -allowcontinue => 1
    );
    print Dumper $ini->{"myparms"};
'
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
$VAR1 = {
          'name2' => [
                       'val1',
                       'val2'
                     ],
          'name1' => [
                       'val1',
                       'val2'
                     ]
        };
```

---

If instead you need a `shell` variable to share, by example if using `bash` :

```
$ echo "export MYVAR=foobar" >> ~/.bashrc
$ . !$
$ perl -le 'use Env qw/MYVAR/; print $MYVAR;'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for something less verbose. I'm going to use this for a list of variables that I'm going to need in almost all my scripts and I don't want to have a bunch of line of setup.

Answer (score 1):

For global variable like that, I have them set in the environment (I use Windows, but obviously you can do the same in Unix).  In Perl, the environment is stored in the `%ENV` variable (part of the system.)  You would refer to your BINDIR as `$ENV{BINDIR}`.